# pass JSON object to protrator params on CLI

Tags: angularjs, protractor

further to [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor), is it possible to pass a JSON object via the CLI? ie *not* via a config file? (rather than just passing a simple string)

ie

```
protractor ... --params={login: {user:"abc", password="abc123"}}
```

rather than:

```
protractor ... --params.login.user=abc --params.login.password=abc123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible in current Protractor. As of this write current version is 1.0.0

But extending it yourself is quite simple. First you should pass valid JSON, so instead of

```
protractor ... --params={login: {user:"abc", password="abc123"}}
```

Pass it like this:

```
protractor ... --params='{"login": {"user":"abc", "password":"abc123"}}'
```

Then within your `onPrepare` section:

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
browser.params = JSON.parse(argv.params);
```

Oh, add `"minimist": "~0.2"` to your package.json or install globally.

Comment: thanks elgalu - haven't tested your answer yet - but it looks very plausible so giving you the tick :-)