# Protractor - run test with different arguments

Tags: command-line, arguments, protractor

I'm trying to find a way to run a test with different arguments through command line. to be more specific- I want to send different login credentials every time I'm calling-

```
$ protractor conf.js
```

maybe something like

```
$ protractor conf.js username,password
```

I know that I can use the configuration file, but it is also hardcoded.

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor)

Comment: yes, I wrote that I know that I can use the configuration file (which was the answer in the issue you have suggested) - but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry. it seems like that's a good solution. thanks.