# Any way to to access protractor capabilities from each individual spec?

Tags: javascript, protractor

Protractor config:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: 'https://example.com/#/',

    params: require('./params/params.js'),

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['incognito', '--disable-cache', '--disable-extensions'],
            prefs: {
                intl: {
                    accept_languages: "fr-CA"
                }
            }
        },
        prefs: {
            'config.http.use-cache': false
        },
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2
    },
}
```

I have some specs that test the French site and the English site. Right now I have to manually change the `accept_languages` property when I switch between tests.

Is there any way to define what language the test  will use from each individual spec file?

I know it's possible to access `baseUrl` via `browser.baseUrl` but I'm not sure how to access the `capabilities` object.

Answer (score 1):

I did this once before (sorry, the details are lost to time) and these two posts helped me make it happen.

[How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor)

[Is there any way to pass multiple browser via protractor cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239378/is-there-any-way-to-pass-multiple-browser-via-protractor-cli)

Basically, you can define and pass in quite a bit of info to the browser object.