# Toggling multiCapabilites config based on cucumber tag

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumberjs

I was wondering if any one had found a way to toggle between different multiCapabilities configurations coming from a cucumber.conf.js file. Currently I have this one config that will run parallel chrome drivers to run tests.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2
}],
```

But what if I also wanted to add a multiCapabilities option for multi browser testing

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},{
    'browserName': 'firefox'
}]
```

I would rather not want to have to comment out or change code, but rather store a number of multiCapabilities configurations that I can toggle either using something like a flag, tag, or grunt option. Has anyone had any luck with something like this? Thanks!

Comment: If you were using gulp it would be trivial to do this programmatically.  Perhaps not what you wanted to hear, but that's all I got.

Comment: Nope, not using gulp - was hopefully looking for a solution outside of task runners. But thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use protractor's in-built command line options for passing browsers or toggling between any such capabilities.

```
Usage: protractor [configFile] [options]
configFile defaults to protractor.conf.js
The [options] object will override values from the config file.
See the reference config for a full list of options.

Options:
--help                                 Print Protractor help menu
--version                              Print Protractor version
--browser, --capabilities.browserName  Browsername, e.g. chrome or firefox
```

If you look at the protractor's **cli options** and if you have more than one browsers setup in your multicapabilties option, you can pass browser names like this -

```
protractor config.js --capabilities.browserName='chrome'
protractor config.js --capabilities.browserName='firefox'
```

You can set this as individual scripts in your **package.json** to run tests in various browsers-

```
"scripts": {
"tsc": "tsc",
"test": "protractor ./config.js",
"chrome-tests": "protractor ./config.js --capabilities.browserName='chrome'",
"firefox-tests": "protractor ./config.js --capabilities.browserName='firefox'"
}
```

Now you can invoke this by using `npm` -

```
npm run chrome-tests // it would run your tests in chrome browser
npm run firefox-tests // it would run your tests in firefox browser
```

You can also make use `params` object in your `conf` file pass paramaters and access them anywhere in your tests or command line.

```
params: {
     primaryBrowser: 'chrome'  // I am biased towards chrome :)
     secondaryBrowser: 'firefox'
 },
```

You can access them in your tests by suing browser's global object -

```
console.log(browser.params.primaryBrowser);
console.log(browser.params.secondaryBrowser);
```

Similarly you can change them in your command line-

```
protractor config.js --params.primaryBrowser='firefox'
```

There is one more elegant way of doing such things through `getMultiCapabilities`-

You can even pass multiple browsers by accessing the above functions object, please refer this link for more details.

[Is there any way to pass multiple browser via protractor cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239378/is-there-any-way-to-pass-multiple-browser-via-protractor-cli)