# angular switch from test ng-app to dev ng-app

Tags: angularjs, mocking, protractor

So here is my problem I want to mock my data when I run tests or am offline but call the extarnal API when I can/want by using somthing like `npm run protractor` and `npm run protractor-mock`.

the solution I have cobbled together is having 2 `index.html` files one with the addition of mock (`index-mock.html`).

So my question is how can I tell setup `protractor-mock` to load `index-mock.html`

Note: as stated in the code `GET('http://localhost:5000...` is bad but not the issue at hand.

my files so far

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="PCA" class="no-js">
...
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

index-mock.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="PCA" class="no-js">
...
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('PCA', [
    'ngRoute',
    'chart.js',
    'ngDialog',
    'ngCsv'
]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/chartContainer.html',
        controller: 'chartContainerCtrl'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}).constant('config', {
    'apiUrl': 'http://localhost:5000'
});
//2nd app ->
angular.module('PCAMOCK', ['PCA', 'ngMockE2E'])
    .run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:5000/').respond({ //yes 'localhost:5000' this is bad but not the issues at hand
            "defaults": {
                "invURL": "http://www.invURL.com",
                "accountURL": "http://www.accountURL.com"
            }});
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:5000/accounts').respond(200, {ciao:'mamma'}, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/^/).passThrough();
        //...
});
```

package.json:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    'tests/*.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to command-line argument in protractor.  See [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor).  You should be able to use this to differentiate between two runs, and to change the URL you pass to `browser.get`?

Not directly your question, but you might want to look into Protractor's support for mock injection.  See [the `addMockModule` docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) or http://eitanp461.blogspot.com/2014/01/advanced-protractor-features.html

You should not need to have two implementations of your app, it can be agnostic to the mock-or-not.