# How do i overwrite protractor.conf.js values from the command line?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I currently have protractor setup to run on our integration server. Inside the protractor.conf.js file i have the following:

```
 multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'platform': 'MAC'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'platform': 'MAC'
  }]
```

I would like to override this when running locally from the command line. I've tried the following with no success

```
protractor --verbose --browser=chrome
```

**Question:** How do i switch to only using a single instance of chrome when running locally from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/b00c822a9ae14af24c4c100aed8274b19cd644ea/lib/cli.js), `browser` command line argument is an alias of `capabilities.browserName`.

According to the [`referenceConf.js` documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/referenceConf.js):

```
// If you would like to run more than one instance of WebDriver on the same
// tests, use multiCapabilities, which takes an array of capabilities.
// If this is specified, capabilities will be ignored.
multiCapabilities: [],
```

In other words, since `multiCapabilities` are specified, `capabilities` are ignored.

---

What you can try to do is to reset `multiCapabilities` from command-line:

```
protractor --verbose --browser=chrome --multiCapabilities
```

As an another workaround, have a separate config file for running a single browser instance.

---

Also, list of related topics:

- [Added support for multiCapabilities object and splitTestsBetweenCapabilities boolean](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner/pull/62)
- [Multicapabilities specs ignore the --specs flag on the command line and run anyway](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2231)

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated to the OP - but what about removing properties like sauceKey: and sauceUser: ? Great response to the OP.

Comment: @JackMurphy thank you! Could you please elaborate more about why is it needed to remove the sauce-related keys?

Comment: When testing locally i would like to use my own browser rather than offloading to sauce labs. using --sauceKey --sauceUser; results in an invalid login to saucelabs. The properties apparently need to be removed.

Comment: @JackMurphy yeah, exactly! I've actually ended up having a separate configuration file..we use browserstack, but we had similar issues.