# How to test registration pages in Protractor, with multiple browsers?

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to use multiCapabilities to define multiple browser drivers, but when I try running a test that registrates THE SAME user in different browsers, all but the first browser that tries to register returns an error (User already exists).

Is there a way to run parallel e2e tests in Protractor with information that cannot be duplicated (like user name, user e-mail and such)?

I found a way to test them, but creating different configs for each browser and defining different params (like user name) for each of them. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at this answer for some help: [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor)

I think you can do this on a per-browser basis in the config, so you should be able to pass in different usernames and passwords that way.