# how can Parametrize protractor-config file for different browsers and test suites

Tags: protractor

I am running my Protractor Test from command `npm run e2e`

I want a way so that if I pass `npm run e2e firefox` then my test will get executed on Firefox browser.

Or if I run `npm run e2e chrome` then it should run on chrome

if I pass both `npm run e2e firefox chrome` then my test should run on both the browser in parallel.

Is it possible to parametrize protractor config file?

Similarly if I can pass test suite name via command and it should execute only  tests under that particular test suite.

Here is my config file and this is what I want to achieve:

```
`//var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {

allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
//Add parameters for browser names
params:{
  pass: {
      browserName : 'chrome',
      testSuitName : 'e2e/TestSuites/_BVT/*.js',
  }
 },  
suites: {    
//Define here List of Sanity Test Scenarios:
  BVT : testSuitName,   
}, 
// configure multiple browsers to run tests
multiCapabilities: [
 shardTestFiles: true,
 maxInstances: 2   
{'browserName': browserName}
],
baseUrl: 'http://mytestUrl/',
 framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
 defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},  
onPrepare: function() {  
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {   
  var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
  var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
         consolidateAll: true,
         savePath: 'tests/test-results',            
         filePrefix: browserName + '-xmloutput',
         modifySuiteName: function(generatedSuiteName, suite) {             
             return browserName + '.' + generatedSuiteName;
         }              
     });
     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
  });    
}, 
resultJsonOutputFile: 'tests/test-results/output.json'    
};`
```

Would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried 
  `capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },` in your spec file? that will allow you to choose your browser.

Comment: yes I did tried, but I want to parametrize browserName : $param value so that I can pass this value from command line and config file will take this value either chrome or firefox or IE..

Comment: would you have a look to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor and the referenceConf.js link https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js you can use params to do that

Comment: @MohamedNAOUALI this shows how can I pass parameters like username, pwd etc to config and use it in my test. But I want my browser value and test suite values to be parametrize. I want my config file to look something like: capabilities: { 'browserName': param1 }, and suites: {
    Test1: param2
   
  }, and when I execute `npm run e2e 'chrome' 'logintest.js'`  command my logintest.js should get executed on chrome browser. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: any idea on this how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is a bit old now, but this solution may help people having a similar problem.

Use multiple config files, one for each browser type, setup a base config file, and require that into each of the other config files, and then create an npm script for each config file.  No need for parameters and everything stacks nicely.

so the base config (called something like "protractor_base.js")would look something like:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  rootElement: '[ng-app]',

  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: ['example-spec.js']
};
```

And then your other configs (ie "protractor_chrome.conf.js") would look something like:

```
protractor = require('./protractor_base.js');
var config = protractor.config;

config.capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
};


exports.config = config;
```

You can then specify a multi browser config, just a chrome one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
--capabilities.chromeOptions.args=headless --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=disable-gpu --capabilities.chromeOptions.args=window-size=1200,600
```

The above code should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for passing parameters from command line to protractor config file  and found a way to do this:

```
npm run e2e -- --baseUrl=http://testurl:8080 --suite=suite_name_defined_in_config --capabilities.browserName=browser_Name
```

where my npm package.json :

```
 "e2e": "protractor tests/protractor-conf.js",
```

and config file contains :

```
suites: {
    BVT: 'e2e/TestSuites/_BVT/*.js',
    Full: 'e2e/TestSuites/Full/**/*.js',      
},
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
```

Comment: If I have a capabilities value which is an array, what is the correct way to pass it as a parameter? For example (that not works): `--capabilities.chromeOptions.args = ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]`