# How to set protractor chromeOptions via command line arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to set the chromeOptions in my protractor config file via the following command:

```
protractor conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args.0 start-fullscreen --capabilities.chromeOptions.args.1 display  --capabilities.chromeOptions.args.2 :99
```

I'm expecting the outcome to look something like this:

```
...
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['start-fullscreen','display',':99']
  }
},
...
```

When I try running the command however, I get the following error in webdriver

```
...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: cannot parse args
from unknown error: must be a list
...
```

I'm unsure how to structure my command line arguments such that it produces args as a list, or if the functionality is simply not supported.

Here is a [post](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2765) where someone tries something similar, where the functionality seems to be intentionally left out. However, [this post](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/3291) seems to imply that the functionality was recently added.

If it is not possible to set via command line, is there a work around? I need to change the display for every protractor call, maybe it can be done in onPrepare via [params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor) (note: params can't be referenced in the conf.js outside of onPrepare).

Answer (score 6):

List of command line arguments to be passed to chromedriver can be constructed by passing multiple `--capabilities.chromeOptions.args` to `protractor`. Each should be followed by equal sign and command line argument itself. There is no need to manually specify positions of arguments in `args` array.

If command line options expects additional argument, its value can be separated from option name using equal sign.

So, in your example, you should use:

```
protractor conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="start-fullscreen" --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="display=:99"
```

---

It should be noted that WebdriverJS expects `chromeOptions[args]` to be an array, while passing single command line switch will coerce it to string. This may be worked around by passing additional, invalid command line switch that will be ignored:

```
# This won't work
protractor conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="start-fullscreen"
# This works as expected
protractor conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="start-fullscreen" --capabilities.chromeOptions.args="fake-arg"
```

That workaround must be used until [issue 4050](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4050) is resolved (patch is available since March, but it hasn't been merged and released yet).