# How to programmatically edit protractor config file to point to correct protractor path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webstorm

Thank you in advance!
We are using protractor to do e2e testing. At this moment we have following steps for any new person to start running our test

---

npm install

an npm task to download webdrivers

manually edit the protractor config's node parameter entry to point to correct path of protractor (inside node modules\protractor\bin\protractor)

---

I am trying to avoid the third step so that everything can be done via either tasks or be there permanent (so no need of a change). So, how can I programmatically set that parameter? or any other better way to handle this situation. It will also help me to attach my tests to the CI builds.

I am using WebStorm at the moment and for no particular reason trying to avoid a grunt or gulp task. However, if that is really needed, can do the same.

Comment: Is it http://stackoverflow.com/a/23137432/2504101 relevant to what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. Thank you for looking into it. I am looking for how to by default have the right parameter so that I can run our test. If you have noticed protractor config in webstorm, you have to edit that config to have correct parameter pointing to protractor

Comment: Oh, sorry, you meant node config.