# How to pass command line arguments to the browser driver being used

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm currently using protractor for some tests. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to pass command line arguments to the actual driver being used.

For example, chromedriver.exe accepts '--whitelisted-ips' as a command line argument. Is there any way, in my protractor config, that I can pass this to chromedriver.exe?

Another example is, with MicrosoftWebDriver.exe, it has a flag called '--package' which allows me to pass the package id of the app to target. How would I get protractor launch the driver with those arguments?

I thought that maybe I could launch the standalone selenium server with an argument to launch the driver with those arguments, but from my investigation I couldn't find a way to make that happen.

Just to clarify, I'm not asking to pass command line arguments into protractor to use in my tests. I want the browser drivers being that are running (chromedriver.exe, firefoxdriver.exe, MicrosoftWebDriver.exe) to be run with specific command line arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor)

Comment: Thanks for the link @SiKing, but not exactly what I was looking for. This is passing an argument so that they can be used in the test files, but I want to pass arguments to the actual driver.exe's that are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Add the arguments to your config file as capabilities.  This is a driver-specific property.

For Chrome/Chromedriver:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./tmp/specs/*.spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName' : 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions' : {
            args: ['--start-maximized']
        }
    }
}
```

For Firefox/Geckodriver (only changes shown):

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName' : 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions' : {
        args: ['-headless']
    }
}
```

MDN has a (very short) [list of vendor-specific capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities#Vendor-specific_capabilities).

See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities for more.

Comment: But how can I do this for other browser's drivers? While this will definitely work for chrome, how can I do this for firefox and edge drivers? It doesn't seem to be supported for those other browsers.

Comment: I believe, for Firefox, you need to use profiles; for example:


`var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
 firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);`