# Is it possible to specify params in Protractor Debug Configuration (WebStorm)

Tags: debugging, protractor, webstorm

I'm using Protractor in Webstorm and in order to use parameters in the terminal I can do `protractor --params.url=http://www.google.com/`
Is there a way to specify params in this configuration so I don't have to type it every time? In a similar way to the screen below
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with webstorm but you should be able to change the values in the `params` object in the config to use environment variables instead of hardcoded values. Example `url: "${LAUNCH_URL}"` or even `url: process.env.LAUNCH_URL`. As long as the names match the env variables you have set it should work.

Answer (score 2):

**Protractor** run configuration doesn't currently support passing command line options to protractor, please vote for [WEB-25165](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25165) to be notified on any progress with this feature.

However, just as @tehbeardedone has mentioned, `params` can be specified in protractor config - see [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration that worked for me

- Open WebStorm
- Click ‘Run’ tab
- Select ‘Edit Configurations…’
- Click ‘+’ button on the top left corner of the newly opened window
- Select **‘Node.js’** configuration from the list

Set  parameters (following examples were used on windows machine)

- Name: ‘Protractor’
- Node interpreter: ‘C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe’
- Node parameters: ‘’
- Working directory:
- JavaScript file: ‘~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js’
- **Application parameters, this is where you specify path to your conf, relatively to working directory^ and then parameters like this**: ‘e2e/**settings**/configs/protractor.custom.conf.js --baseUrl="https://stage.mysite.com" --params.login="testuser" --params.password="test_USER00"’
- Environment variables: ‘’

This config works great in my project, where we solely rely on async/await syntax