# Error debugging protractor with node 8 async/await and angular 6

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I can not get the protractor debugger to work with node 8 async/await and Angular 6. Going back to node 7 in the old way with `elementExplorer`, `browser.pause()` and `browser.debugger()` is not an option. Also because in the future, the `control flow` is being removed from Selenium and I keep reading that it's a better debugging experience using node 8 async/await instead of `control flow`.

I am using angular 6.0.3, angular CLI 6.0.5, node 8.11.2 & chrome 71.0.3578.98. I reproduce the problem by generating a test app with CLI:

```
ng new stack-overflow-debugging-protractor --style=scss --routing
```

Generating this app with angular CLI automatically installs & configures protractor 5.3.2.

I have a simple test that runs `ng e2e` with succes:

```
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    browser.get('/');
    expect(element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
  });
});
```

[I follow this document to set up my debugging environment](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)

To make it work with async/await I need to disable `control flow` so in `protractor.conf.js` I add `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` and in `./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json` I change `"target": "es5"` into `"target": "es2017"`

In the e2e test I add `async` and `await` and add the command `debugger`

```
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  it('should display welcome message', async () => {
    await browser.get('/');
    debugger;
    await expect(element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
  });
});
```

When I execute `ng e2e` it still runs with succes:

I run the debugger in a teminal session:

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js
```

I open chrome inspector `chrome://inspect/#devices` in browser, find the current running target and click on `inspect`. Then I click on the button `resume script execution` (or F8), and the test should pause at the first line with the `debugger` keyword.

But it doesn't and Chrome automatically opens a new window with an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. The console of Chrome DevTools is empty. The terminal session gives:

```
E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:4200/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
```

So I read the suggestions and add `getPageTimeout: 60000` to `protractor.conf.js` to . Then I get error:

```
Failed: Error while running testForAngular: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
```

Seems like the same error so I change `protractor.conf.js` line `allScriptsTimeout: 11000` into `60000`. Then I get error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
(node:11716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 'fail' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
(node:11716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which wasnot handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Again, so I change `protractor.conf.js` line `defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000` as a part of `jasmineNodeOpts` into `60000`. Same error.

I also tried a higher value, 200000, but in result the wait is longer but error is the same.

Who knows a solution for this problem?

Comment: what IDE do you use to develop your code?

Comment: I use VS Code to develop

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but I would suggest you to try debug in webstorm. Very robust when you use with async/awaits and intuitive. I had just solved today my last problem with it and can pass parameters to run configuration. You can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945455/is-it-possible-to-specify-params-in-protractor-debug-configuration-webstorm/53782925#53782925

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I switched two years ago from webstorm to vscode. I don't want to go back !! When I debug in vscode I get the same error message.  I special reproduced my problem with a terminal session and no IDE to make sure the problem is not the IDE.

Comment: Running protractor from command line won’t automatically start your application to run tests against. Do you run ng start in another terminal window before executing protractor? Or alternatively you should be able to do node —inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/ng e2e. Don’t have a laptop to try it, but otherwise everything you do looks correct.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin: thanks a lot, you gave me the answer to my problem. When I start `ng serve` in a separate terminal session it work. It makes sense that protractor won't start my application to run tests against.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin: Could you create an official answer so that I can approve it and other people can benefit from this knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Protractor directly won't automatically start an application to run tests against, this is part of the work `ng e2e` command does.

To fix the issue you can either start application in the separate terminal window using `ng serve` or probably you can run debugger against `ng e2e` command (which will start an application under the hood):

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/ng e2e
```