# Protractor - How to use tags on Jasmine for e2e testning

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, tags

I'm having some issues where I am stuck on what to do to be able to tag different tests that I want to run.

The tests that I want is only required at the end where I want to be able to tag which payment I would like to pay which is Mastercard, Visa or Amex. I do have a test that does the details page such as writing users information, choose shipment but then at the end I do have multiply options that I would like to test pending on what I want to test:

paymentPage.js

```
describe('Payment page', function () {
    paymentPage = new PaymentPage();

    // The details page is accessible by the specified URL
    it(`Credit Card - Has a form that can receive user data`, async function () {

        await paymentPage.creditCardPayment();

    });


     //Visa
    it('Enets payment', async function () {
            //TODO

    });

     //Amex
    it('Enets payment', async function () {
            //TODO

    });
});
```

As you can see there is 3 options that I would like to test so whenever I do etc "protractor e2e run mastercard" so that means it should run the first test case, if I choose visa then do the second test case and skip the rest basically.

However I do have couple of tests that executes before coming to the payment page but they all need to do the same for each payment so meaning that all test cases before payment needs to do exactly the same thing everytime (So I guess we just need to do tags at the payment to let the script know which payment to choose)?

How can I do a sort of tagging or maybe someone has another solution that is better? That I can be able to choose what payment provider I want to run

edit:

```
exports.config = {

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                'incognito', 'disable-extensions', 'start-maximized', 'disable-infobars', '--window-size=1920,1080'
            ]
        },
        loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' },
        platform: 'ANY',
        version: ''
    },


    specs: [
        'pagesDesktop/testPage.js',
        'pagesDesktop/paymentPage.js'
    ],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        reporter: "mochawesome",
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
    },

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    framework: 'jasmine',

    params: {
        cardType: {
        }
    }

};
```

---

```
describe('Payment page', function () {
    paymentPage = new PaymentPage();

    console.log(browser.params.cardType);

    if (browser.params.cardType === "mastercard") {
        // The details page is accessible by the specified URL
        it(`Credit Card - Has a form that can receive user data`, async function () {
            await paymentPage.creditCardPayment();
        });
    }
```

Comment: `if/else` condition? and start protractor with a parameter

Comment: Hmm how do you mean? How would I be able to do that etc? @SergeyPleshakov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add if/else logic

```
describe('Payment page', function () {
    paymentPage = new PaymentPage();

    // The details page is accessible by the specified URL
    it(`Credit Card - Has a form that can receive user data`, async function () {

        await paymentPage.creditCardPayment();

    });


  if (browser.params.cardType === 'visa') {
    it('Enets payment', async function () {
            //TODO

    });
  } else if (browser.params.cardType === 'amex') {
     //Amex
    it('Enets payment', async function () {
            //TODO

    });
  }
});
```

You can read how to parameterize teste here [How can I use command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135649/how-can-i-use-command-line-arguments-in-angularjs-protractor), or here 
https://medium.com/@nicklee1/making-your-protractor-tests-data-driven-e3c9e2a5e4e7

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie check the links, it has everything

Comment: Hmm I believe by doing: ```params: {
        cardType: {
            mastercard,
            enets,
            installment
        }
    }
```  

Wont probably work for me because we dont have any values inside it, right? - I have checked your links and it seems like they only have values inside it

Comment: no you can start your config with a command passing parameters `-parames.cardType="amex"`

Comment: but then it returns: `{ '0': 'm',
  '1': 'a',
  '2': 's',
  '3': 't',
  '4': 'e',
  '5': 'r',
  '6': 'c',
  '7': 'a',
  '8': 'r',
  '9': 'd' }` :( - I will update what I did:

Comment: Please check the thread that I have updated, Maybe I did something wrong :(